# How can i copy duplicates from one array to another in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration

Lets say i have

```
array1=[1,2,1,1,5]
```

How can i search for any duplicates and put them into another array for example array2, but only if there are more than 3 of a kind?

my goal is

```
array2=[1,1,1]
```

Comment: I suggest starting with reading documentation on [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html) and [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html). They have everything you need here.

Comment: You need to be more specific here. Does order need to be preserved? Do you also need them removed from the original array?

Comment: no order or remove only interested in storing duplicates in another array if there are more than 3 duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using select you can get the elements in your `array1` which are present 3 or more times, as I see in your expected ouput:

```
array1 = [1,2,1,1,5]
array2 = array1.select { |e| array1.count(e) >= 3 }
p array2
# [1, 1, 1]
```

In case there are no elements repeated 3 or more times, then array2 will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
array1.group_by(&:itself).select { |_, v| v.size >= 3 }.values.flatten
#=> [1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This preserves order and has O(n) time complexity, `n` being the size of the array.

```
array1 = [3,2,1,3,2,1,1,5,2,1,3,3]
array1 - array1.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }.
                select { |_,cnt| cnt <= 3 }.keys
  #=> [3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
g = array1.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n]+= 1 }
  #=> {3=>4, 2=>3, 1=>4, 5=>1}
h = g.select { |_,cnt| cnt <= 3 }
  #=> {2=>3, 5=>1}
a = h.keys
  #=> [2, 5]
array1 - a
  #=> [3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

[Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a default value (here zero) is often called a *counting hash*. If `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h` has no key `k` then `h[k]` returns the default value `0`.

When Ruby encounters the expression `h[k] += 1` the first thing she does is expand it to

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If `h` has no key `k` this becomes

```
h[k] = 0 + 1
```

Foregoing the snytactic sugar, the former expression reads

```
 h.[]=(k, h.[](k) + 1)
```

It is the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) that returns the default value, not the method [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).